# How to save selected multiple Lightning check box values in the backend and show them on UI?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript

I need to save selected multiple values from `lightning-checkbox-group` in the backend, which should show on the UI after refreshing the page.

I am able to select values but not able to show them in the backend. how can I save the selected values and display them on UI?

```
<lightning-checkbox-group name="Price Based"
                                 label="Price Based"
                                 options={options}
                                 value={value}
                                 onchange={handleChange}>
</lightning-checkbox-group>
```

JS:

```
  get options() {
    return [
        { label: 'Price Low', value: 'option2' },
        { label: 'Price Medium', value: 'option3' },
        { label: 'Price High', value: 'option4' },
    ];
}


  handleChange(e) {
    this.value = e.detail.value;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-checkbox-group/example), you can get the selected values as a Comma separated String from `selectedValues`. Store this value in the backend. Then retrieve the value from backend, use `split` and assign back to the `value` array. This will mark the selected checkboxes as checked.

```
selectedValuesBackend = "";
value = ['option1'];

get options() {
    return [
        { label: 'Ross', value: 'option1' },
        { label: 'Rachel', value: 'option2' },
    ];
}

get selectedValues() {
    return this.value.join(',');
}

handleChange(e) {
    this.value = e.detail.value;
    this.selectedValuesBackend = this.selectedValues;
}
//set existing selected value by user 
connectedCallback(){
    this.value = this.selectedValuesBackend.split(',');
}
```

Comment: Hi Saroj Bera, Should I save this data in a Text field?

Comment: You can store the String in a Text field.